# Install Onboard on-screen keyboard on Fedora 21

Tags: fedora, software-installation, compiling, keyboard

I am looking for guide to install Onboard keyboard on Fedora.
https://launchpad.net/onboard

Looks like there is not package for this distributive and I should compile it from source. How do I do it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just download the tarball, decompress it, step into the folder it creates, then run the setup script (setup.py).

That's just a quick rundown - I've never installed it, so make sure you read the README in the extracted directory.